# ActionBarCompat : Crash with actionprovider before searchbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I'm facing a weird issue with ActionBarCompat. I'm inflating menu with an ActionProvider and ActionView in Menu. Every thing goes well if I define **ActionView** infront of **ActionProvider**. If I reverse the case, that is when I use ActionProvider infront of ActionView, android is throwing a **classcastexception** to inflate ActionView.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share_PIC"
    actionbardemo:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    actionbardemo:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share Pic"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_itemsearch"
    actionbardemo:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    actionbardemo:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

When I declare like this, it is crashing in **OnCreateOptionsMenu**.

Please help me out.


Sha

Answer (score 0):

This Weird issue is also having the weird solution. I donno why, but when I tried with the same code as mentioned above, Now its working....

I'm unable to believe this behavior... hope this issue wont show up in future....